# Importing XML into InDesign and automatically adjusting content

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, xml

My client has an InDesign catalog. Instead of manually updating it as he's done up to now, he'd like to import XML data into the InDesign file and not have to make any of the changes manually. However there is one major problem, the pages in the document tend to be very uneven in their layout. One page might be fairly airy while the next may barely contain all of the elements it needs to. As a result, my client needs to make the copy smaller on some pages. Is there a way to automate the size of the text from one page to the next when making an import so as to avoid overset text?

Comment: If any of the answers below is satisfactory, please tick the "accepted answer" tickmark next to it. Good for you, me, us.

Answer (score 1):

If you are making all the text in the frame smaller, you can apply a scale change to the frame itself. Then the text is technically unmodified.

Answer (score 0):

Typefi autofit comes closest to that:

http://www.typefi.com/typefi-publish/typefi-autofit